# How to access Azure SQL Edge using ODBC on ARM64

Tags: sql, azure, odbc

I wish to port a Django app to an Azure IoTEdge device (Raspberry Pi) and use Azure SQL Edge to store the data.

The Raspberry Pi is running Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, but it seems that Microsoft don’t have an ARM64 ODBC driver available.

I have the database up and running and can connect from elsewhere so I’m confident on that part. I have the setup running with 2 containers, for Django and Postgres, but for ease of implementation I would prefer to use SQL Edge.

I have the desired setup running on other devices (Mac).

Does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks